# Json file format to csv in r

Tags: r, json, csv

I have JSON format file which is in .log extension sample data is as follows 
   "header": {
        "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
        "sourceSystemType": "CUSTOM"
      },
      "body": {
        "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
        "createTimestamp": "1575284734366",
        "stringPoints": []
      }
    }

```
  "header": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "sourceSystemType": "CUSTOM"
  },
  "body": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "createTimestamp": "1575284734631",
    "stringPoints": []
  }
}

  "header": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "sourceSystemType": "CUSTOM"
  },
  "body": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "createTimestamp": "1575284735224",
    "stringPoints": [
      {
        "name": "空调主机/电机线圈温度2/主机1",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "13.2599992752075",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "空调主机/电机线圈温度2/主机2",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "5.87747175411144E-39",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      }
    ]
  }
}

  "header": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "sourceSystemType": "CUSTOM"
  },
  "body": {
    "systemId": "WsCrgenstd_RTM_74",
    "createTimestamp": "1575284735364",
    "stringPoints": [
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_1_1",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_1_2",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_1_3",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_1_4",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_2_1",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_2_2",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_2_3",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "name": "末端空调箱/风机运行状态/AHU_2_4",
        "dataTimestamp": 1575284700000,
        "value": "0",
        "status": "OK",
        "pointType": "STRING"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want convert this into CSV file format using R. Can some one help me on reading the file and converting it.
My output should look like this as in the image [image]

Comment: How would your output look like? This structure contains an array: `stringPoints`. How should this be represented in a csv file?

Comment: @TobiSH Output should look like:  systemId, createTimestamp, name, dataTimestamp, value, status, pointType should be column names with there respective values

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which will help to convert Json to csv file.
i am not sure what you have post here is exact json or not.
but following will definately help.

```
d1 <- fromJSON(r1,simplifyVector = TRUE)

write.csv(d1,'mydata.csv',rows.name=F)
```

where r1 is your json file
d1 is your data frame and
final csv file is mydata which can save in your directory if you excecute command write.csv.

Comment: I am getting this error while reading               Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
                               "header": {      "systemId": "WsCrgenst
                     (right here) ------^    @Tushar Lad